# Is there something in C that prevent my large numbers from turning into "6.95278e-310". I would like the full number to be printed

Tags: c, floating-point, double, precision, scientific-notation

I'm coding a number evaluation function in C, but the function returns 6.95278e-310 instead of the desired 69562562845134572345342423424 for example. How would I go about returning the full number instead of scientific notation?

Comment: It's not an issue of what value a variable holds but instead of how it's printed. I've linked a question about how to display large floating point numbers using decimal instead of scientific notation.

Comment: @JohnKugelman If I wanted to pass the FULL number into a write() do I need to do anything specific or just pass it in normally?

Comment: 6.95278e-310 is a very, very small number, not 69562562845134572345342423424.

Comment: Note that doubles generally support at most 16 meaningful significant digits. In many use cases fewer digits will be meaningful.

Comment: Printing  6.95278e-310 without scientific notation would take printing lots and lots of zeros and would take about 5 lines to print.

Comment: When `(s)printf()` is insufficiently accurate, could roll a helper function [Function to print a double - exactly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/212490/function-to-print-a-double-exactly)